# simulation study using AIC

Tags: r, simulation, linear-regression

I have to code a simulation study in R. So, I have X1,...,X15~N(0,1) explanatory variables and Y~N(2+2*X1+0.8*X2­1.2*X15, 1) and I need to simulate n=100 values and repeat that for iter=100 times. Then, for each linear model created I have to calculate the AIC­values and, finally, find the best model. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do that for item=100 times. I wrote the code for 1 simulation, which is the following:

```
set.seed(123)
n<‐100
p<‐15
iter<‐100 X<‐matrix(rep(NA,n*p),ncol=p) for (j in 1:p) {
X[,j]<‐rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1) }
mu<‐(2+2*X[,1])+(0.8*X[,2])‐(1.2*X[,15]) Y<‐rnorm(n = 100, mean = mu , sd = 1) 
sim<‐data.frame(Y,X)
d<‐lm(Y~X, data = sim)
```

But how I do the rest I have to do, i.e.the 100 simulations and the calculations of AIC? I'm really new to R, so I am quite confused.

Comment: Don't completely rewrite the question, the code, the assumptions, and the requirement that `stepAIC` is used. Start a new question if you want another answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
nsim <- 100
nobs <- 100
nvar <- 15

results <- lapply(1:nsim, function(i) { 
     X <- matrix(rnorm(nobs*nvar),nrow=nobs)
     y <- rnorm(nobs, mean=2 + X[,c(1,2,15)]%*% c(2, .8,-1.2))
     DF <- data.frame(y, X)
     lm(y ~ X, data=DF)})
```

That should give you your simulations. Now find the "best"

```
findbest <- which.min(sapply(results, function(i) { AIC(i) }))
results[[findbest]]
```

Since all data are simulated using the same underlying data-generating process any variation in AIC is essentially random variation.